# Setting button to remember users selected page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a project and I have to make a button to remember users selected specific page. It should work like a cookie, but I need some more information about how to save website page on cookies. The main part is when users clicks on a button, website remember users selection and when users enter after some time the same page, he will see his selection. And of course, if user push the button one more time, his selection deletes.

P.s. I'm new guy in coding so, your help will be useful for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not idea to store all the user selection preferences. You can use localstorage in javascript which works across all browsers. Based on the page hash, you can store the section.

Comment: I just need it to get internship in one company

Answer (score 1):

You can use browser storage for this

When user select some value:

```
localStorage.setItem("userSelection", "selection-value");
```

And when the user enter on page, you verify if `userSelection` exists:

```
var userSelection = localStorage.getItem('userSelection');
if ( userSelection ) {
    // some action
}
```

See more: [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 0):

Use any of these below to store user preferences

```
    sessionStorage.setItem("sessionData", "I am set in session storage.");  
localStorage.setItem("localData", "I am set in local storage.");
```

My recommendation is to store preference using URL hash combination while.storing in session or localstorage

Answer (score 0):

you can do that based on ids like in my example right bellow

```js
function getCookie(name){
 var b=name+"=",
 c=decodeURIComponent(document.cookie),
 d=c.split(";");
 for(var e=0;e<d.length;e++){
  for(var f=d[e];" "==f.charAt(0);)f=f.substring(1);
   if(0==f.indexOf(b))return f.substring(b.length,f.length)
 }
}

function setCookie(name,value,period,path){
 var time=new Date;
 time.setTime(time.getTime()+1e3*(60*(60*(24*period))));
 document.cookie=name+"="+value+";"+"expires="+time.toUTCString()+";path="+(path?path:"/")
}

function removeCookie(cookie_name){
 if(getCookie(cookie_name)){
  document.cookie=cookie_name+"=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;";
 }
}

document.getElementById('xxx').onclick = function(){
  if(getCookie(this.id)==1) {
    removeCookie(this.id)
  } else {
    setCookie(this.id,1,999999);
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="xxx">Selection 1</button>
```

and of course use php or maybe javascript to detect if cookie exists.